# How do I pass relationship properties as parameters in the .net neo4j client?

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I'd like to pass in parameters into a query so that I can use relationship properties in CreateUnique.  I'd prefer to use the parameters rather than just doing a string format so that it can protect (Am I right in aassuming parameters are cypher injeciton protected?) against cypher injection.

```
   var query = client.Cypher.Start(
                new CypherStartBitWithNodeIndexLookup("left", AUTOINDEX, PrimaryIndexKey, uname),
                new CypherStartBitWithNodeIndexLookupWithSingleParameter("right", AUTOINDEX, luceneQuery)
                ).CreateUnique("left-[r:Installed {DeviceId:{DeviceId},OS:{OS}}]->right").Return<Software>("right");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** It was a simple addition in the end so I just went ahead and added it. As of 1.0.0.517, the proposal linked to below is now implemented and available on NuGet.

Your query can be:

```
var query = client
    .Cypher
    .Start(
        new CypherStartBitWithNodeIndexLookup("left", AUTOINDEX, PrimaryIndexKey, uname),
        new CypherStartBitWithNodeIndexLookupWithSingleParameter("right", AUTOINDEX, luceneQuery)
    )
    .CreateUnique("left-[r:Installed {DeviceId:{DeviceId},OS:{OS}}]->right")
    .WithParam("DeviceId", 123)
    .WithParam("OS", "Windows 8")
    .Return<Software>("right");
```

---

You can't do this in a nice way right now.

Yes, Cypher parameters are all safe from injection. We pass them across the wire in an entirely different construct that keeps them separate from the query text. In Neo4j, they are stored independently of the query's execution plan.

I've opened an issue at https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/issue/66/support-custom-parameters-in-cypher-fluent, with a proposed syntax, so that we can implement it. If you review the proposal and collaborate over there, we can get this in pretty quickly.

As a workaround, you could *probably* do:

```
var query = client
    .Cypher
    .Start(
        new CypherStartBitWithNodeIndexLookup("left", AUTOINDEX, PrimaryIndexKey, uname),
        new CypherStartBitWithNodeIndexLookupWithSingleParameter("right", AUTOINDEX, luceneQuery)
    )
    .CreateUnique("left-[r:Installed {DeviceId:{DeviceId},OS:{OS}}]->right")
    .Return<Software>("right")
    .Query;

query.QueryParameters.Add("DeviceId", 123);
query.QueryParameters.Add("OS", "Windows 8");

var results = client.ExecuteGetCypherResults<Software>(query);
```

I wrote that code right here in the answer box though, and haven't tested it, and it's horrible, and ugly, and I'd kind of like you to not use it.

Comment: Pull requests are accepted equally as fast. ;) This is why we have almost 600 tests.

Comment: Did this work? Can you accept the answer or raise an issue if there's a problem?